# In Swift 4 Xcode 9, if you load and present a Nib as follows, how do you dismiss it?

Tags: ios11, swift4

In Swift 4 Xcode 9, if you load and present a Nib as follows, how do you dismiss it? This is an extract of my code in another ViewController from which the Nib gets loaded.

```
 @objc func doPresent(_ sender: Any?) {
    if let svc = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SecondViewController", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? SecondViewController {
    svc.data = "This is very important data!"
    svc.delegate = self
    self.present(svc, animated:true)
    }
  }
```

I tried:

```
self.view.subviews[0].removeFromSuperview()
```

and

```
self.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

as well as

```
self.dismiss(animated:true)
```

None of the three have the desired result. The first one removes a button from the Nib, the second just gives me a dark screen and the third dismisses the view in which the Nib is embedded to the original view in the navigation view.

Comment: did you try self.dismiss ?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss

Comment: yes I did. thanks for pointing out. I'll add it to the post

Comment: I mean, did you call `self.dismiss(animated:true)` from the presented view controller (svc) ? the svc needs to have a close button or something, from where you call this code.

Comment: The button calling the dismiss resides on the Xib and the owner of the Xib is the ViewController loading the Xib. Let me update the question with more info. Thanks for asking the right questions.

Answer (score 0):

I declared svc as a var at the class level and was able to use

```
self.v.removeFromSuperview()
```

That did the trick for me.